# Strange JS performance issues

Tags: javascript, performance

I'm having issues with my string distance function working too slowly. I've narrowed it down to the following (the time is for 10K string comparisons):

```
// desired behavior - 400ms
dp[c + 257] = Math.min(dp[c + 256] + 1, dp[c + 1] + 1, dp[c] + (a[i] != b[j]));

// this is somewhat faster - 300ms
dp[c + 257] = Math.min(dp[c + 256] + 1, dp[c + 1] + 1);
dp[c + 257] = Math.min(dp[c + 257], dp[c] + (a[i] != b[j]));

// even faster - 50ms
dp[c + 257] = Math.min(dp[c + 256] + 1, dp[c + 1] + 1);
dp[c + 257] = Math.min(dp[c + 257], dp[c] + (a[i] != b[j] ? 1 : 0));
```

So first of all, splitting up a `Math.min` into two calls is faster than using it once with 3 arguments - how is that possible? Second, why is adding an explicit tertiary expression so much faster than relying on the implicit conversion from bool to int?

Here's a fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/6bnLvbt6/

Comment: It doesn't surprise me that type conversion is more expensive than no type conversion. Type conversion isn't free.

Comment: Instead of a jsfiddle I suggest you create a jsperf

Comment: But `a[i]!=b[j]?1:0` is also basically type conversion, except its done explicitly in JS and surely should be more expensive than the native one?

Comment: In V8, [`Math.min` with arity 2 follows a completely different code path from `Math.min` with arbitrary arguments](https://github.com/v8/v8/blob/77c19034f482c40d215a437751a08854b36c5579/src/js/math.js#L111).

Comment: Oh, `Math.min` is actually implemented in JS and not in native code??

Answer (score 2):

You've got 3 test cases:

1. `Math.min` with **3** arguments with a type cast (bool to int)
2. **2** `Math.min` calls with **2** arguments each where the second call has a type cast
3. **2** `Math.min` calls with **2** arguments each without the type cast

There is also another difference between 1 and 2&3 where there is an extra `+ 1` on some of the arguments. I think this is a bug.

The implicit type cast seems to be the most expensive. If you remove the implicit type cast from `1` you get:

```
dp[c + 257] = Math.min(dp[c + 1], dp[c + 256], dp[c] + (a[i] != b[j] ? 1 : 0));
```

This takes `250ms` (vs `60ms` for 3). This still shows that `Math.min` with 3 arguments is slower. Let's investigate more.

If you simplify the test case to:

```
// 1
for(var i = 0; i < 10000; i += 1) {
    Math.min(1, 2, 3);
}
// 2
for(var i = 0; i < 10000; i += 1) {
    Math.min(1, 2);
    Math.min(1, 3);
}
```

The results on my machine are: `1` takes `2500ms`, `2` takes `87ms`. If you add more arguments to `Math.min` you'll see that it neatly increases in time by `500ms` per extra argument, this reveals something about the implementation.

Browser vendors optimize functions that are used often. If `Math.min` with more than 2 arguments is uncommon these results are not strange. What you're seeing here is that `Math.min` has two implementations: one for two arguments, which is really well optimized, and another for more arguments, which isn't optimized. For v8 this is confirmed by apsillers: [v8 source on github](https://github.com/v8/v8/blob/77c19034f482c40d215a437751a08854b36c5579/src/js/math.js#L111)

Comment: The question is more of a 'why is Math.min implemented in such a way that manually unrolling it is so much faster, when its supposed to be a native function (otherwise I'd simply write `a<b?a:b`)' and 'why is an implicit type conversion from bool to int slower than x?1:0 when its does the same'.

Comment: Optimization is all about using as much information as you have. If your information is _"I have more than 2 numbers"_ you know less than when you can say _"I have exactly 3 numbers"_. `Math.min` could have an implementation that is fast for 3 numbers by writing code that compares 3 numbers (a bunch of if-statements). Why is that code not written? Probably because nobody thought it was important. If you're comparing 3 numbers a lot write your own `math_min_3` function.

Comment: Why is an implicit boolean to number cast slower? Again because you add information to make it faster. If you know before hand you've got a boolean you don't need an expensive discovery of what the type of a variable is.

Comment: My guess is that `a<b?a:b` is even faster than using `Math.min`. Why? For one because there is no function overhead and second because you know more. `Math.min` has to deal with any of the arguments being `NaN`. If you know (or don't care) that any of your arguments are `NaN` you can use that to write a faster implementation.